# Let $T$ be a compact and self adjoint operator on a hilbert space $H$ such that $T$ is not invertible. Prove that $\text{Ker}(T)\ne 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let us assume on contrary that $\text{Ker}(T)=0$.

Now we will use a standard result which says $\text{Ker}(T)=\overline{\text{Ran}(T^*)}$

As $T$ is self-adjoint, $T=T^*$. So $\text{Ker}(T)=\overline{\text{Ran}(T)}$.

Therefore, $\overline{\text{Ran}(T)}=H$.

From here, I can't proceed. If I can show $\text{Ran}(T)$ is closed we are done. Although I haven't use the compactness of $T$ yet.

Can anyone help me complete the proof? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Compact operators are never invertible for infinite-dim spaces. In particular, their range cannot be closed.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the assumption that $H$ is not separable?

Comment: @daw Okay, I understand. If $T$ is compact then $\text{Ran}(T)$ is separable. So we need the condition of $H$ being non-separable.

Comment: Yes, you are right if $T$ is invertible and compact $T$ will have finite rank, which is not possible for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim is not true for separable $H$. Define $T:l^2\to l^2$ by
$$
Tx = (x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3,\dots),
$$
which is compact, self-adjoint, and injective. It is not invertible as $(1,1/2,1/3,\dots)\in l^2$ is not in the range of $T$.

If $H$ is non-separable then the claim follows from the spectral theorem.

Comment: Okay, I understand. If $T$ is compact then $\text{Ran}(T)$ is separable. So we need the condition of $H$ being non-separable.

Comment: Yes it has a countable orthonormal basis

Comment: @copper.hat somehow mistyped (non)-separability here, corrected now.

Comment: @daw Could you elaborate on how the claim follows from the Spectral thm?

Comment: By the spectral theorem, $H = E\oplus \ker T$, where $E$ is spanned by the (countably many) eigenvectors to non-zero eigenvalues, $E$ is separable, so $\ker T$ cannot be just $\{0\}$ if $H$ is non-separable.

Comment: @daw Ah yes, I see. Thanks for the clarification.